# shouldComponentUpdate does not work in react-native

Tags: react-native

**this is a simple demo.**

```js
//data demo 
{
   filterOption:{id:'xxx',name:'yyy'},
   list:[{id:'xxx',name:'yyy',msg:'zzz'},...]
}

// Component demo
class Root extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(newProps){
       console.log(newProps) // work
    }
    render(){
      let { filterOption, list } = this.props;
      return <View>
               <Filter filterOption={filterOption} />
               <List list={list} />
            <View>
   }
}
class Filter extends React.Component{
   shouldComponentUpdate(newProps){
       console.log(newProps) // not work
    }
   render(){ // <NativeFilter> is a native Component. 
      return <NativeFilter />
   }
}
```

**question:**

shouldComponentUpdate method in Filter not work. someone can help me ? when props.list changed , I want to prevent the Filter rerender

Comment: you can use app state along with componentWillReceiveProps to control <Filter /> component visibility.

Comment: check this -> https://snack.expo.io/By2E2IX0x

Answer (score 3):

you have to return a boolean value based on condtion whether it need to refresh or not

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
   return nextState.count != this.state.count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`shouldComponentUpdate` trigger on props/state changes.

**Reference DOC:** [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

**Implementation Example :**

```js
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Object, nextState: Object) {
    return (
      !_.isEqual(nextProps, this.props) || !_.isEqual(nextState, this.state)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`shouldComponentUpdate` is only called on props/state changes. Since your code doesn't change state/props in or above the `Filter` component, there is no need to call `shouldComponentUpdate` (which is not called for initial mounting render).